# routing from angular tabs directive example

Tags: angularjs

How can you use the href link in the angular tab directive to go to a view via routing. Somehow I think you have to add the root scope to the directive.

appTreeDirectives.directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            var panes = $scope.panes = [];

```
        $scope.select = function(pane) {
            angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
                pane.selected = false;
            });

            pane.selected = true;
        }

        this.addPane = function(pane) {
            if (panes.length == 0)
                $scope.select(pane);

            panes.push(pane);
        }
    },
    template:
    '<div class="tabbable">' +
    '<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">' +
    '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">'+
    '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)"> <i class="fa fa-list-alt fa-lg"></i></span> {{pane.title}}</a>' +
    '</li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
    '</div>',
    replace: true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write hashtag into a href to navigate.

```
<a href="#/viewName">Navigate to a view</a>
```